# CSS - Animate parent width when child element is removed

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a `div` container inside a flex container with set maximum width. When a child is removed the width will decrease. Is it possible to animate the width change with just CSS?

```js
function remove(el) {
  var element = el;
  element.remove();
}
```

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
}

#parent {
  max-width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

#child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#other {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child" onclick="remove(this)">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="other">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do with pure CSS. The animation is based on the width changes, so you need to set the width of `#child` to 0 by Javascript. To remove `#child` completely, you can delay it with `setTimeout`.

```js
function remove(el) {
  var element = el;
  
  el.style.width = 0; //trigger the animation with width changes
  
  setTimeout(() => {
      element.remove();
  }, 500); //0.5 seconds

}
```

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
}

#parent {
  max-width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

#child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 0.5s; /* Width animation in 0.5 seconds */
}

#other {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child" onclick="remove(this)">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="other">
  </div>
</div>
```